# Button on email that would execute a php code

Tags: php, html, database, email, outlook

Is it possible to add a hyperlink button on outlook emails that would execute php code?

Here's an example, I've created a computer request form which looks like this:

[New Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y26u.png)

And when you click on the "new request" button it becomes completed which looks like this:

[Completed Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CW7a.png)

By the way, when you send this form it sends the information through email as well.

So is it possible to have like an `approve` button on the mail and when you click that `approve` button it would execute that button and make the request completed.

Or if you could link me an article, I can't find any articles about it.

Comment: only if that button was a link to a web site

Answer (score 2):

Outlook does not run any scripts or process web forms as a security measure. A static link is the best you can get. Now your server is of course free to do whatever it wants when processing the HTTP GET request in response to the link click.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to host your PHP script somewhere and provide a link. The script will execute when users click the link. You can supply variables to the script via the query string or a POST body